# Identify an old story about a Doctor, who uses some dark magic to summon a devil

Tags: story-identification

My English teacher in school once mentioned an old story about a genius Doctor, who tries some dark magic to summon a devil, but ends up with some tragic or bad results.

I forgot the name but the story seemed really dark and interesting.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/154591/edit) any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where?

Comment: On top of the above, please try to add more details, as of now, it's far too broad to give any constructive answers.

Comment: Assuming the inspiration was Faust (genius doctor learns magic /  summons Devil / ends badly), there are more than a dozen "[inspired works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faust#Literary_appropriations)" listed on Wikipedia alone. That makes this too broad, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds quite a lot like something very old, [Goethe's Faust, Part I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faust,_Part_One) to be specific:

> [...] the Lord challenges Mephistopheles, the Devil, that Mephistopheles cannot lead astray the Lord's favourite striving scholar, Dr. Faust.
>
> We then see Faust in his study, who, disappointed of science with natural means, attempts and fails to gain knowledge of nature and the universe by magical ones.
>
> [...] Mephistopheles, who offers Faust a contract: he will do Faust's bidding on earth, and Faust will do the same for him in hell (if, as Faust adds in an important side clause, Mephisto can get him to be satisfied and to want a moment to last forever). Faust signs in blood [...]

He doesn't actively summon the devil himself, but from a quick translation or interpretation it might seem like that.

If you want to have a look, you can [read the book online or as an ebook](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/14591), since it's copyright expired long ago.

Comment: Or possibly the play that the original inspired; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Faustus_(play)

Comment: Good one. In my (one-track) mind, an old story about a Doctor would have been one published between 1963 and 1997.

Comment: @MrLister Well, I never read it myself, but here in Germany every German teacher will mention Faust sooner or later, so it's basic promise is rather well known and I immediately made that connection. It could be something more modern of course.